# How to connect to SQL database with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sql

I have a third party database program on one of our servers.  With Windows XP we simply create a desktop shortcut which starts the application (\apps-server\icad\msassets.exe).
When I attempt to run the same shortcut on my Windows 7 (32 bit) laptop (Dell 3340) it starts but I get an error saying it cannot connect. The error states:

```
SQLSTATE=IM002
   [MICROSOFT][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
   default drive specified
```

This is the code in the .ini file:

```
 [odbc]
    dbms=ODBC 
    dbpass=sql
    DelimitIdentifiertodb = "no"
    logid=
    logpass=
    servername=
    DbParm=ConnectString='DSN=MCSO_SQL11;UID=dba;PWD=sql'
```

This has worked with previuos versions of Windows.

Comment: What is the name of the third party database program ?

Comment: is this a SQLServer DB and do you have to use an ODBC driver? is OleDB or ADO, or SQL Native client an option? if not, check out Control panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources for an interface to install odbc drivers and create system and user DSNs.

Comment: Good answer Frank Thomas. I was trying to remember the terms.

Answer (score 2):

Your XP machine probably had the MySQL (or other SQL DB) ODBC connector software/drivers installed and an entry created in the XP ODBC/Data Sources control panel inside "Control Panel" -> "Administrative Tools" -> "Data Sources".

You can install the (MySQL) ODBC connector/drivers on Windows 7 so your application should continue to run. Ideally, though, the application should be migrated (rewritten) to use the SQL connection without ODBC.

For further information and to download the connector software see the MySQL website: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/